# How to perform convolution using Fourier Series

Tags: matlab, sum, continuous-integration, convolution, fourier-descriptors

OK let me cut to the chase.

I am trying to use MATLAB to 
(i)generate the fourier series based on known coefficients and thereafter 
(ii) determine the output function when the impulse is known.

So far I used this code to obtain the fourier series:

```
clear all
syms x k L n
evalin(symengine,'assume(k,Type::Integer)');
a = @(f,x,k,L) (2/(pi*k))* sin((pi*k)/(2 * L));
fs = @(f,x,n,L) (1/2*L) + symsum(a(f,x,k,L)*cos(k*2*pi*x/L),k,1,n);
f = x;
pretty(fs(f,x,11,1))
```

This works as desired. Now the impulse response is as follows:

```
h = heaviside(x) * exp(-5*x);
```

Now, in order to obtain the function, we need to perform the convolution with the respective functions.But when I input the following, I get the error:

```
x1 = fs(f,x,1,1);
conv(h,x1)

Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
Error in conv (line 38) 
c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) is only defined for numeric inputs.  If you want to find the convolution symbolically, you'll have to input the equation yourself symbolically using integration.

If you recall, the convolution integral is defined as:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)</sup>

Therefore, you would do this:

```
syms x tau;
F = int(h(tau)*x1(x-tau),'tau',-inf,+inf);
```

[`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) is a function in MATLAB that does symbolic integration for you.  Also note that the convolution integral is commutative, and so this also works:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)</sup>

Therefore, you should also get the same answer if you did:

```
syms x tau;
F = int(h(x-tau)*x1(tau),'tau',-inf,+inf);
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem at all. If this works, please consider accepting my answer. Good luck!

Comment: actually I went about this by doing the multiplication in the s-domain. I am nor sure how to accept answers BTW.. and not enough rep to upvote as well

Comment: @IsmailPatel - Accepting is done by going to the top of my post and clicking on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down voting arrows to the left.

Comment: @IsmailPatel - Ah, that's much more smarter.  Good use of the Laplace property!